# motor or actuator which fits these specifications

Tags: motor

This is a repeat question with more details;

As a hobbyist and blissfully ignorant of electrical engineering, I wonder if someone out there is willing to give me some feedback?

Is there a battery driven device available (motor / actuator or both) that is able to advance and retract a rod a distance of 3/4 to 1¼ inches with a force of app. 1-2 lbs. at a speed of no more than 1 sec. per application (one forward- or one reverse motion)?

At the same time it needs to fit into a box max. 2 1/2” x 2 1/2” by ½ inch deep (including battery). I know that is a pretty tall order because - although my own research has identified some amazing miniature motors - there are all lacking in at least one of my requirements, mostly my limitations on size.

Thank you in advance for your valued insight or information.

Comment: Repeat / duplicate questions are not allowed. You need to edit your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429777/miniature-motor-or-actuator) and add the new details. When readers see the updated question, if they believe the question is answerable, contains enough details and is within the site rules, they can vote to re-open it. I suggest reading [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) from the [help] for more information.

Comment: Changing the range of operation from 1-1/4" to the range 3/4 to 1-1/4" in no way justifies posting this as a new question. This question is too broad because it requires us to repeat your research and determine if there is something that you overlooked. If someone has worked on a similar problem they are likely to respond by comment. Someone that can easily determine that this can't be done is also likely to comment. You probably need to do more research, not ask more questions.

Comment: Not only are duplicates not allowed, this type of question simply does not belong here.  Your problem is *mechanical* not electrical, and regardless part-to-purchase questions were long ago deemed off topic as a category - for better or worse, those are the rules of this site.  There's a whole Internet of other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I sympathize with your problem with your question keep getting rejected by moderators.

They expect you to know some basic physics to specify not the just the weight but the max. tolerable force to acceleration, max speed then the reverse deacceleration to reach the displacement of 1-3/4" max (45mm) with a mass of 2 lbs plus rod ( 1kg) and in your expected of 1 second.

THen have enough gear friction to stop without sinking.

Not only that it has to fit in 2.5"x2.5"x0.5" box with a battery.

But you didn't specify how many operations this tiny battery should operate for or even if it is a rechargeable battery with some remote control or toggle switch.

You also don't have any diagram of the object being moved, the mechanical mounting, brackets needed and what the purpose of this customer servo actuator.

So if you do a rough cut on your design and if you can fill in all the blanks I mentioned above, it may be possible with a lot of thought and work.

Lead-screw, or pulley timing belt with start-stop switches ... this is not trivial.

And its a lot more mass than opening a DVD tray and would need at least 2 Li-Ion cells not leaving much space for the servo motor.

This is custom and nothing exists to do what you want, even if we knew what it was for, but that would help. A lot.

My first thought is this is not easy to do in the limited space without a real purpose.